# Why is a bilinear map $M \times N \to B$ the same as a homomorphism $M \to Hom_R(N,P)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra" states that:

It is elementary that a bilinear map $M \times N \to P$ is the same as a homomorphism $M \to Hom_R(N,P)$

While this makes some intuitive sense I keep hand waving an explanation to myself.

I would really like to see it done out at least once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $\varphi: M\times N \to P$ is a bilinear map, then the corresponding homomorphism is $\phi: M\to \hom_R(N,P)$, with $\phi(m)(n)=\varphi(m,n)$. We can check $\phi(m)$ is a homomorphism from $N$ to $P$ using the fact that $\varphi$ is bilinear.

Convesely, if  $\phi: M\to \hom_R(N,P)$ is a homomorphism, then the corresponding bilinear map is $\varphi: M\times N \to P$, with $\varphi(m,n)=\phi(m)(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: To a bilinear map $f:M\times N\rightarrow P$ associated $H_f:M\rightarrow Hom_R(N,P)$ defined by $H_f(m)(n)=f(m,n)$.

And to $H:M\rightarrow Hom_R(N,P)$ associate $H_b:M\times N\rightarrow P$ defined by $H_b(m,n)=H(m)(n)$  show that the correspondence are inverse each other

Answer (score 1):

Given a map $f : M\times N \to P$ which is linear in the second argument, there is an associated map $F : M \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(N, P)$ defined by $F(m)(n) = f(m, n)$. If $f$ is also linear in the first argument (i.e. $f$ is bilinear), then $F$ is a homomorphism.

Conversely, given a map $G : M \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(N, P)$, there is an associated map $g : M\times N \to P$ given by $g(m, n) = G(m)(n)$. Note that $g$ is linear in the second argument, and if $G$ is a homomorphism, $g$ is also linear in the first argument (i.e. $g$ is bilinear).

This establishes a natural bijection between bilinear maps $M\times N \to P$ and homomorphisms $M \to \operatorname{Hom}_R(N, P)$.

Answer (score 1):

Eisenbud's statement is morally correct, but not strictly true with the usual set-theoretic representations of functions (or any representation that I know of). Writing $X \to Y$ for the set of set-theoretic functions from $X$ to $Y$, then there is a 1-1 correspondence between $X \times Y \to Z$ and $X \to (Y \to Z)$ that associates $f:X \times Y \to Z$ with $x \mapsto y \mapsto f(x, y)$ and associates $g : X \to (Y \to Z)$ with $(x, y) \mapsto g(x)(y)$. This is known (to computer scientists and logicians at least) as [currying and uncurrying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying).

If you look at functions that are required to preserve algebraic structure, this correspondence doesn't work in general. However, for modules over a ring, the correspondence does restrict to a 1-1 correspondence (indeed an isomorphism of modules) between bilinear maps $M \times N \to P$ and homomorphisms $M \to \mbox{Hom}_R(N, P)$. ($\mbox{Hom}_R(N, P)$ is a subset of the set $N \to P$ of all functions from $N$ to $P$). This is the sense in which Eisenbud means the two things are the same.